# Flutter: How can I pass values in the constructor so I can reuse my widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am quite puzzled about the values being passed in the class constructor not being available in the Widget.

I am passing the value of the cards in the widget constructor, but when debugging it and after they are build the Text widgets do not have any text.

Initializing the Widget with the values.

[image]

Debugger shows the cardValue fields with no value.
[image]

Empty Widget:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```dart
class PockerCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String cardValue;

  const PockerCard({Key key, this.cardValue}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PockerCardState createState() => _PockerCardState();
}

class _PockerCardState extends State<PockerCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.cardValue),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add at least an explanation, do not just put the code for copy/paste...